# how to send email in laravel5 using mailgun

Tags: laravel-5

i am using mailgun driver for sending emails, i am trying with this code,

```
foreach ($login_history as $number)
{
$authentication = 
authentication::select('email')->where('phone_no','=',$number)->get();
Mail::send('loginreminder.reminder',['number' => $number], 
function($message) use($authentication) {
$message->to($authentication,'user')->from('no-
reply@xyz.co','Admin')->subject('Login reminder');
});
return "success";
}
```

but i am getting the below error.
ErrorException in SimpleMessage.php line 297: Illegal offset type

Answer (score 0):

`$authentication` is an instance of an Eloquent Collection. You must first of all call `->first()` instead of `->get()` to get an actual model (assuming you only have a single `Authentication` entry per phone number). Then, access the email on that model:

```
foreach ($login_history as $number)
{
    $authentication = authentication::where( 'phone_no', '=', $number )->first();
    Mail::send( 'loginreminder.reminder', ['number' => $number], function ($message) use ($authentication)
    {
        $message->to( $authentication->email, 'user' )->from( 'no-reply@xyz.co', 'Admin' )
                ->subject( 'Login reminder' );
    } );

    return "success";
}
```